# Using custom models.py module name with custom user account app in Django

Tags: django, module, model

I have a custom user account model which I use in the settings like so;

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user_account.UserAccount'
```

This obviously refers to `user_account.models.UserAccount` model class. Though, I would like to rename the `models.py` module to `user_account_models.py`, in which case django naturally complains about `user_account.UserAccount` not being exist.

I've checked the doc, and models are stated in `app.ModelName` format, nothing in between to refer to where the model is "since django assumes they will always be in `models.py` in every app" I assume.
Is there a way to make django use custom names for `models.py` module (or any module for that matter) for a particular app (since every app will have it's own distinctive name with the app name as prefix)?

**SOLUTION & UPDATE 1**

I've overwritten `import_models` method of the `AppConfig`, which seems to be working. However, I do not know whether it would have side effects.

```py
class UserAccountConfig(AppConfig):

    name         = 'user_account'
    verbose_name = 'User Account'

    def import_models(self):
        self.models = self.apps.all_models[self.label]

        if module_has_submodule(self.module, 'user_account_models'):
            models_module_name = '%s.%s' % (self.name, 'user_account_models')
            self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
```

Comment: Just import the model into `models.py` after writing them wherever you want?

Comment: I got various other errors when I did that. Is there a way to refer to the modules explicitly in some cases at all? Thanks a lot for your time!